# Trying to generate a custom ID after querying a database

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this data table of folders and files. Each file in the file data table belongs to a folder in the folders data table. So to ID each file, and which folder they belong to, I employ this kind of ID System.

*Park909.1*: *Park909* denotes the folder, and the *1* is the number ID of the file.

What I'm trying to do is that whenever I add a file to a folder, I want to query the files data table, count how many of those files exist, set that count to a variable, add to that variable, and then concatenate the variable to a string, and then pass that as the ID. Here is the code I have at the moment.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $password) or die("error connecting: ".mysqli_error());
if($conn->connect_error){
echo "connection error";
}

//this query checks if files exist that are bound to the folder I'm working on
$check = "SELECT * FROM files_dt WHERE folder_ID = '".$folderID."'";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check);

//This section does not return true even though the same $check query on my database return more than 1 row
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rowcount++;
$fileID = $folderID.".".$rowcount;
}
```

I think there might be something wrong with the way I'm using the mysqli_num_rows() function. I've tried changing to mysqli_affected_rows(), I've tried changing and removing the *>0* portion of the if statement. All attempt have not returned a "true" result. the file does not return any error messages.

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Where does `$folderID` come from? Please edit question and explain.

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting for the PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and using `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query and tell us if you get any errors back and what they were.

Comment: $folderID comes from the page this was directed from, because I'm dealing a database, and data tables are almost 1000 records and more, I had to off load the the variable passing through Post method functions. These are bound to values that already exist in the database, so sql injection is mitigated.

Comment: I included error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of my php code, in my actual file, and tested the page with every change I could think of. No Error messages were passed.

Comment: One thing you have to convince: that the value of `$folderID` in the php code matches (exactly) a value of `folder_ID` in the `files_dt` table. It says "_the same $check query on my database returns more than 1 row_". Do you copy/paste this query to run it? Or do you have to enter a folderID to run in database language?

Comment: yes, I copied and ran the query on the database, and I pulled a Folder ID to run the sql query test.

At the moment I want to look into alternatives, and workarounds to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol. The problem was that I did not select a database to query. As a result, the query was not completed. Rookie mistake. Only needed to add a line of code to select my database.